# MS Word API: table values not set

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins

Using the Office JavaScript API, I am trying to fill a selected table using the following code:

```
 Word.run(function (context) {
        var table = context.document.getSelection().parentTable;

        context.load(table);

        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (table.isNullObject == true || !table) {
                    console.log("selection ist not table");
                    errorHandler("selection is not a table");
                } else {
                    // loop over table
                    for (var row = 0; row < table.values.length; row++) {
                        for (var column = 0; column < table.values[row].length; column++) {
                            console.log(table.values[row][column]);
                            table.values[row][column] = "Test " + row + " " + column;
                        }

                        context.sync().then(function () {
                            console.log("done"); 
                        }).catch(function (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        });
                     }
               }
            });
      });
```

The scripts runs fine, the table object exists, the values are logged and the final "done" too. But the table stays as it is - no update of the values. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments about the code you've posted:

- Checking for `isNullObject` on the `table` object like your code is doing is not effective, because the lines above that will have already thrown an error if the `parentTable` doesn't exist.
- Error handling (`catch` statement) should be located immediately after the `Word.run` -- that way it'll catch any error that occurs inside the `Word.run`.
- Instead of loading the entire `table` object like you are, you should only load the properties that you need (in this case, `values` and `rows/items/cells/items/body`).
- To set a cell value, use the `insertText` method on the `body` of the cell that you want to update.

The following code sample incorporates this feedback, and should successfully update the values in your table.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var table = context.document.getSelection().parentTable;

    table.load("values, rows/items/cells/items/body");

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            for (var row = 0; row < table.values.length; row++) {
                for (var column = 0; column < table.values[row].length; column++) {
                    console.log(table.values[row][column]);
                    table.rows.items[row].cells.items[column].body.insertText("Test " + row + " " + column, "Replace");
                }
            }

            return context.sync()
                .then (function() {
                    console.log("Done");
                });
        });
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Great question @BernhardWebstudio! To explain why your specific code doesn't work is because the add-in code is invoked in a separate process from the Office Application and it must make 'requests' to actually acquire the data. This is similar to asking for attributes within a REST or OData call. (e.g. $select)

What does this mean for you? Well with a just slight alteration to your code you just need to request what properties of the table you want to load. Since you only care about the values of the table, it would be easy to do this with this type of code. If you notice I also have a commented out line that is `table.load("[Property Name]");` to use the Office Apps Object model as proxy objects as well. Kim has pointed out some other really good suggestions as well. Cheers and Happy Coding!

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    let table = context.document.getSelection().parentTable;
    //table.load("values");
    context.load(table, "values");

    //...
```